# Работа с Picasso android в AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, picasso

Загружаю png изображение через Picasso по url, вот только перед `relativeLayout.setBackground` выдает исключение что я использую main поток, вызов `SetBackground` идет в методе `OnCreate`.

Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread.
>                         at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.checkMain(Utils.java:136)
>                         at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:496)
>                         at com.example.user_android.otvchat.MainActivity$SetBackground.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:386)
>                         at com.example.user_android.otvchat.MainActivity$SetBackground.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:367)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageButton btn;
private TextView txtMain;
private TextView txtSecond;
private TextView txtSecond2;
private EditText editPhone;
private EditText editCode;
private Button back;
private boolean numberPhone = true;
private boolean saveNumber = false;
public static String NUMBER_PHONE = "";
public static String NUMBER_PHONE2 = "";
public static String userID;
private int code;
private int editCodePush;
private boolean rules;
SharedPreferences sPref;
String url;
final String SAVED_PHONE = "saved_phone";

RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
String URL = "****";

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    txtMain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    txtSecond = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    txtSecond2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    editPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    back.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    editCode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    txtSecond2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    txtSecond.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    editPhone.addTextChangedListener(new MaskedWatcher("+38 (###) ###-##-##"));
    setTitle("Авторизация");
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://sms.binovery.gq/img/heart-back.png").into(new Target(){
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            relativeLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmap));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (saveNumber) {
                if (editPhone.getText().toString().equals(sPref.getString(SAVED_PHONE, ""))) {
                    NUMBER_PHONE = editPhone.getText().toString();
                    new ShowDialogAsnc().execute();
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavigationDrawer.class);
                    intent.putExtra("regulations_btn", R.id.button6);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            } else if (true) {
                new ShowDialogAsnc().execute();
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                Spannable text = new SpannableString(txtSecond.getText());
                text.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 100, 104, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                txtSecond.setText(text);
                txtSecond.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                editPhone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                txtMain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtSecond2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                NUMBER_PHONE = editPhone.getText().toString();
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            editCodePush = Integer.parseInt(editCode.getText().toString());

                            if (editCodePush == code) {
                                sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
                                ed.putString(SAVED_PHONE, NUMBER_PHONE.toString());
                                ed.commit();
                                if (!rules) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavigationDrawer.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("regulations_btn", R.id.button6);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Regulations.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Не верно введен код", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Не верно введен код", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Номер телефон введен не корректно", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    });

    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            back.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            editCode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtSecond2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            txtSecond.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            editPhone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (true) {
                        new ShowDialogAsnc().execute();
                        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                        Spannable text = new SpannableString(txtSecond.getText());
                        text.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 100, 104, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        txtSecond.setText(text);
                        txtSecond.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                        editPhone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        txtMain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        editCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtSecond2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        txtSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        NUMBER_PHONE = editPhone.getText().toString();
                        editCode.setText("");
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                if (numberPhone) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Regulations.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                try {


                                    editCodePush = Integer.parseInt(editCode.getText().toString());

                                    if (editCodePush == code) {
                                        if (!rules) {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavigationDrawer.class);
                                            intent.putExtra("regulations_btn", R.id.button6);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        } else {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Regulations.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Не верно введен код", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Не верно введен код", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

            });

        }
    });


}



private class ShowDialogAsnc extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    String phone;
    JSONObject jsonObjectCode;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        phone = editPhone.getText().toString();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            NUMBER_PHONE = phone;
            jsonObjectCode = new JSONObject(new PostExample().PostExampleMethod("phone_number", phone));
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            code = jsonObjectCode.getInt("code");
            rules = jsonObjectCode.isNull("read_rules");
            userID = jsonObjectCode.getString("id");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> вот только перед relativeLayout.setBackground выдает исключение что я использую main поток

Исключение как раз говорит об обратном:

> Method call **should happen from the main thread**

То, что Вы создаете и запускаете `SetBackground extends AsyncTask` в `onCreate` (то есть из главного потока) в данном случае не значит ничего, так как метод `doInBackground(...)` `AsyncTask`'а выполняется уже не в в главном потоке.

При загрузке изображений с помощью Picasso нет необходимости самостоятельно создавать новый поток, так как Picasso уже сам работает асинхронно.

Методы `relativeLayout.setBackground` и `Toast.show()` можно вызвать только из главного потока, а Вы пытаетесь вызвать их в методе `doInBackground(...)` `AsyncTask`'а, о чем Вам и говорится в стек-трейсе.

Для решения проблемы просто уберите `AsyncTask` и загружайте изображения прямо в методе `onCreate(...)`.

**UPD**. Picasso хранит ссылку на инстанс `Target`'а в виде *weak reference*, которая может быть почищена Garbage collector'ом. Эту проблему можно решить сделав ссылку на `Target` сильной (*strong*).

**Первый способ:**

Добавляете

```
private Target mTarget;
```

как поле класса `MainActivity`.

Далее в методе `OnCreate()` создаете `mTarget`:

```
mTarget = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        relativeLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmap));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

и после этого загружаете изображение:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://sms.binovery.gq/img/heart-back.png").into(mTarget);
```

**Второй способ:**

Реализуете интерфейс `Target` в Вашей `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Target {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        relativeLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmap));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(final Drawable errorDrawable) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(final Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    ...

}
```

А в методе `onCreate(...)` загружаете изображение:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://sms.binovery.gq/img/heart-back.png").into(this);
```

Comment: Переписал в OnCreate, вот только после вызова и загрузки изображения фон не меняется, выводится только Toast тот который в onPrepareLoad(Loading...)

Comment: @Heaven, Покажите весь код этой активити.

Comment: Обновил выше код

Comment: @Heaven, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить asynctask этим методом executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)

Comment: "Сильная ссылка" помогла, спасибо больше)